# Jest jest.fn it's being called but the expect fails

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, ts-jest

I am new to testing with jest, and I wrote the below test.
I mocked with jest a function and passed it as a parameter.
however when run the test, in the logs I can see the function onSuccess was called.
but the expect fails with the error below the code.

how am I supposed to assert the onSuccess = jest.fn() was called?

**Test**

```
 it('should create product correctly', async () => {
            const store = mockStore()
            const onSuccess = jest.fn(() => console.log("I was called"))
            const onError = jest.fn()
            const CreateProductApiMock = CreateProductApi as jest.Mock
            const productRequest = {id: 1} as Product

            CreateProductApiMock.mockResolvedValue(Promise.resolve({
                data: "any"
            } as AxiosResponse<string>))


            await store.dispatch(createProduct(productRequest, onSuccess, onError, "jwt"))
            expect(CreateProductApiMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({"id": 1}, "jwt")
            expect(onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
        })
```

Logs:

```
console.log src/__tests__/components/product/product-slice.test.ts:133
    I've was called


Error: expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

Expected number of calls: 1
Received number of calls: 0
```

Comment: Why you use `await` on the last 3 lines? Is your action async?

Comment: yes the action is async it is calling an api,
I believe the await should be only in the first from the last 3 lines, to await until the action is processed. question edited

Answer (score 1):

Add `await onSuccess` right before `expect(onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`

Like so:

```
...
await onSuccess;
expect(onSuccess).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

What about mocking `dispatch`? Then call your action and check if was called, something like:

```
const dispatch = jest.fn();
await createProduct(productRequest, onSuccess, onError, "jwt")(dispatch);
expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(dispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith({"id": 1}, "jwt");
```